# Kafka: Can we limit a number of messages per key?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose I want to remain not more than 100 recent messages per key in Kafka topic. Can I reach this policy somehow? For example can I configure compaction policy to store recent N messages (not only one per key)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Kafka consumers can seek to any point in the log, including the last 100 messages.

Comment: I want to evict old messages storing only 100 recent messages per each key. For restore reasons I need to have not more than 100 recent  messages for each unique key.

Comment: That's not how Kafka works. You'd need to code this logic into your application / restore process.

Comment: Kafka now stores all messages in file and delete them (in my case) by retention policy from time-to-time. After retention it's only 1 message per key is present in topic but I want 100 messages per key after retention. Seems Kafka is not suitable for my task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way that Kafka provides. Kafka doesn't remove logs (kind of compaction) based on message-based recency. It rather depends on the time-lapse & size of a log file.